# Is castling possible with a pawn promoted to a rook?

Tags: rules, castling, pawn-promotion, loopholes

I was thinking about some rules and I came up with a really nice question. Is it possible to castle with a pawn promoted to a rook?

If the rules are followed-neither the king or the new rook has moved and king doesn’t move out of or through check-to me it seems to be a legal move.

If it possbile, how would this castling look like? I suspect that the king would go to e3, and the new rook would go to e2, starting from the below diagram.

```
[FEN "8/4P3/8/8/8/8/8/4K3 w - - 0 1"]

1. e8=R
```

Comment: The promoted Rook is on the eight rank, the King, not to have moved, must be on the first rank: how would castling be even possible?

Comment: See also [Did Bobby Fischer castle with a pawn promoted to a rook?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8201).

Comment: Please take a look at the pictire of @RemcoGerlich. It is showing this possition. It even was possible before. But now it is restricted by rules. So my question I actually not so bad. I do not understand why somebody is downwoting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, according to FIDE's [Laws of Chess](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=207&view=article), castling has to be done along the first rank.

§3.8.2:

> 3.8.2 by ‘castling’. This is a move of the king and either rook of the same
> colour along the player’s first rank, counting as a single move of the
> king and executed as follows: the king is transferred from its
> original square two squares towards the rook on its original square,
> then that rook is transferred to the square the king has just crossed.
>
> 3.8.2.1   The right to castle has been lost:
>
> 3.8.2.1.1 if the king has already moved, or
>
> 3.8.2.1.2 with a rook that has already moved.
>
> 3.8.2.2   Castling is prevented temporarily:
>
> 3.8.2.2.1 if the square on which the king stands, or the square which it must cross, or the square which it is to occupy, is attacked by one
> or more of the opponent's pieces, or
>
> 3.8.2.2.2 if there is any piece between the king and the rook with which castling is to be effected.

Comment: The rules have evolved over time to exclude more and more of these obscure possibilities. The loopholes are often pointed out / discovered by problemists who produce impossible looking problems which rely on some strange loophole in the rules. Another clever one is that when you promote a pawn it must be to one of your pieces not your opponent's. Old rules didn't have this restriction until someone produced a mate in 1 problem relying on a pawn promotion which uncovered a check with the promoted piece being an opposition knight taking away a flight square from the king.

Answer (score 19):

This question really needs a diagram with this position:

```
[FEN "8/8/4P3/3p4/2p3p1/1pP1kPPp/1P5P/R3K2R w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

White to mate in 3.

Tim Krabbé and Max Pam found the loophole in the rules that you are asking about -- when they composed this problem in 1972, the promoted rook did indeed enable castling, as the rules only talked about a rook that hadn't moved yet! The rule was changed because of this problem.

The solution is beautiful as there are three different castlings involved:

1. 1.e7 Kd3 2.e8=R gxf3 3.0-0-0#.
2. 1.e7 Kxf3 2.e8=R d4 3.0-0#.
3. 1.e7 Kxf3 2.e8=R Kg2 3.0-0-0-0#!.

Comment: I guess white has to promote to a rook in the first variation also, so that `2... Kc2` can be answered by extra long castling.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen: that's what I get for just typing variations from a Google hit... it's more symmetrical too

Comment: Although 3.Qe2# also works in that case.

Answer (score 2):

It used to be a thing(Krabbe), but FIDE edited its rules to be more specific, so that a king could only castle sideways. So, sadly, it isn't possible nowadays.